# Android: Recreate android fragment when language change in settings

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity and using fragments, Using same activity all the time and replacing the fragments. I have a customkeyboard in the first fragment.It opens when i click on the edit text.

The problem is when I am in the first fragment and got to settings and changing the language all other views like bunch of textviews and editexts are refreshing to language selected but here custom keyboard is not opening when i click on the edittext.

I tried hiding it on Onresume() if the view instance is already there but nothing is working

Now i want to restart the activity or fragment when i go to setting and change the language. so that the app can start fresh.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        String str = Locale.getDefault().toString();
        if(str.equals("de_DE")){

            Intent  Intent  =  getIntent (); 
            finish (); 
            startActivity ( Intent ); 
        }

        super.onResume();
    }
```

Doing the above code in my activity but it is not working

Tried detaching and attaching the fragment also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Replacing fragments with FragmentManager (i wouldn't recommend this(it is heavy task resource wise))
2. Implementing interface for fragments and then you can manually change content for desired language